# MySQL - Group By Latest and Join First Instance

Tags: mysql

I've tried a few things but I've ended up confusing myself.

What I am trying to do is find the most recent records from a table and left join the first after a certain date.

An example might be

```
id | acct_no | created_at          | some_other_column
 1 |  A0001  | 2017-05-21 00:00:00 | x
 2 |  A0001  | 2017-05-22 00:00:00 | y
 3 |  A0001  | 2017-05-22 00:00:00 | z
```

So ideally what I'd like is to find the latest record of each `acct_no` sorted by `created_at DESC` so that the results are grouped by unique account numbers, so from the above record it would be `3`, but obviously there would be multiple different account numbers with records for different days.

Then, what I am trying to achieve is to join on the same table and find the first record with the same account number after a certain date.

For example, record `1` would be returned for a query joining on `acct_no` `A0001` after or equal to `2017-05-21 00:00:00` because it is the first result after/equal to that date, so these are sorted by `created_at ASC AND created_at >= "2017-05-21 00:00:00"` (and possibly `AND id != latest.id`.

It seems quite straight forward but I just can't get it to work.

I only have my most recent attempt after discarding multiple different queries.

Here I am trying to solve the first part which is to select the most recent of each account number:

```
SELECT latest.* FROM my_table latest
JOIN (SELECT acct_no, MAX(created_at) FROM my_table GROUP 
BY acct_no) latest2
ON latest.acct_no = latest2.acct_no
```

but that still returns all rows rather than the most recent of each.

I did have something using a join on a subquery but it took so long to run I quite it before it finished, but I have indexes on `acct_no` and `created_at` but I've also ran into other problems where columns in the select are not in the group by. I know this can be turned off but I'm trying to find a way to perform the query that doesn't require that.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have changed my ans please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try a little edit to your initial query:

```
SELECT latest.* FROM my_table latest
join (SELECT acct_no, MAX(created_at) as max_time FROM my_table GROUP 
BY acct_no) latest2
ON latest.acct_no = latest2.acct_no AND latest.created_at = latest2.max_time
```

Comment: ah that seems to work, thank you. It's a little slow but I'm adding a muli-column index to `acct_no` and `created_at` to see if that makes it any better. I just need to figure out the join on the most recent record after a certain date now but I think I know how to do that part.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the id where max date is created.

```
SELECT latest.* FROM my_table latest
join (SELECT max(id) as id FROM my_table GROUP 
BY acct_no where created_at = MAX(created_at)) latest2
ON latest.id = latest2.id
```

Comment: thanks, just tried it but I get multiple results for each account number instead of the most recent?

Comment: select max(acct_no) from myTable 
  GROUP BY created_at having created_at =max(created_at)

Comment: what is the result of this ?

Comment: ohh dear you have same table wait a min

Comment: you've gave some ideas but it's not the max `acct_no` that I am looking for, I think you've got it the opposite way, I want to group by `acct_no` and sort by `created_at` whereas you are grouping by `created_at` and getting the max `acct_no`

Comment: @martincarlin87 welcome it is helpful it's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Trying a different approach. Not sure about the performance impact. But hoping that avoiding self join and group by would be better in terms of performance.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT mytable1.*, IF(@temp <> acct_no, 1, 0) selector, @temp := acct_no FROM `mytable1` 
JOIN (SELECT @temp := '') a
ORDER BY acct_no, created_at DESC , id DESC
) b WHERE selector = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e2886/2)